# ASP.NET UpdateProgress not disappearing after redirect to another page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have page with UpdataPanel and UpdateProgress on it. in this page I redirect to a download page that is responsible for downloading a generated file. 
Redirecting to download page occurs in UpdatePanel via one of controls click event. 
The problem is after downloading the file UpdateProgress does not disappear. 
(I set ContentType of my download page to proper mime type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to download a file in one of events in update panel.
I used i frame to do this. `onClick` event i add inline `iframe` to the page with address of my file.

```
var script = @"
var iframe = document.createElement(""iframe"");
iframe.src = '{0}';
iframe.style.display = ""none"";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(string.Format(script, url));
```

this solved my problem.

Comment: I dont understand what you have done. this code is in the onClick event which start the progress bar yes?. when i try to place this code it tells me the is no 'RegisterStartupScript' which takes only 1 argument